# Setup a button to act as default back button in android device with phonegap/jquery

Tags: android, cordova, button, back

I'm trying to use this script to set a button on my application(html+css+js+jquery) that does the same as the default button of the android device.

This is the script:

```
  </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a.back').click(function(){
         if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1){
            parent.history.back();
            return false;
         }
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Then i have something like this in my code that uses the scrip:

```
          <a class="back">
                <img src="back.png" id="back" style="width: 75%;"></a></div>
```

This works well in the internet browsers but when compiling with PhoneGap does not work on android device...

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using ?

Comment: Im using Dreamweaver CS6 PhoneGap Build.. do not know how to see the version there..